# Minimal realization of a state space model?

Tags: matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Minimal realization of a transfer function is about cancelling out poles against zeros.

But the minimal realization of a state space model is about cancelling out non-controllable and non-observable states.

My question is how I can do that? Can I use PBH (Popov, Belevich, Hautus)-test to find which each eigenvalue gives non-controllable or observable state?

$$\operatorname{rank} ([(A-\lambda I) B]) = n \forall \lambda $$

$$\operatorname{rank} ([(A-\lambda I); C]) = n \forall \lambda $$

After I have found the states who are uncontrollable or unobservable. Can I then create a new state space model without those states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of finding the minimal state space model I think would be using the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition). This allows you to find a similarity transformation that makes it easy to split the state space model into a minimal (controllable and observable) and non-minimal (not controllable or not observable) form.

When calculating this decomposition you could use the Hautus test, but you could also use the controllability and observability matrix. I made a quick implementation of both in MATLAB, whose code can be seen below.

**Hautus test:**

```
function [M, Ak, Bk, Ck, N] = kalman_decomp_hautus(A, B, C)

[V,D] = eig(A);
n = length(A);

M1 = []; M2 = []; M3 = []; M4 = [];
N = zeros(1, 4);
for k = 1 : n
    tempC = rank([A - D(k,k) * eye(n) B]) - n;
    tempO = rank([A - D(k,k) * eye(n); C]) - n;
    if tempC == 0
        if tempO == 0
            M2 = [M2 V(:,k)];
            N(2) = N(2) + 1;
        else
            M1 = [M1 V(:,k)];
            N(1) = N(1) + 1;
        end
    else
        if tempO == 0
            M4 = [M4 V(:,k)];
            N(4) = N(4) + 1;
        else
            M3 = [M3 V(:,k)];
            N(3) = N(3) + 1;
        end
    end
end
M = [M1 M2 M3 M4];

Ak = M \ A * M;
Bk = M \ B;
Ck = C * M;
```

Using this implementation does have the downside that the decomposed state space model matrices can have complex numbers, because if the original $A$ matrix (assuming it is real valued) has complex conjugate eigenvalues then its eigenvectors will be complex conjugate as well, and therefore the similarity transformation also. You could of course try to detect this, but I just wanted a working example.

**Controllability and observability matrix:**

```
function [M, Ak, Bk, Ck, N] = kalman_decomp_matrix(A, B, C, tol)

cc = ctrb(A, B);
oo = obsv(A, C);

Sc = rref(cc')'; Sc = Sc(:,1:rank(cc));
Nc = null(cc');
So = rref(oo)'; So = So(:,1:rank(oo));
No = null(oo);

M1 = rref(round(Sc * (Sc \ No),tol)')';
N(1) = rank(M1);
M1 = M1(:,1:N(1));
M2 = rref(round(Sc * (Sc \ So),tol)')';
N(2) = rank(M2);
M2 = M2(:,1:N(2));
M3 = rref(round(Nc * (Nc \ No),tol)')';
N(3) = rank(M3);
M3 = M3(:,1:N(3));
M4 = rref(round(Nc * (Nc \ So),tol)')';
N(4) = rank(M4);
M4 = M4(:,1:N(4)); 
M = [M1 M2 M3 M4];

Ak = M \ A * M;
Bk = M \ B;
Ck = C * M;
```

I have not done many tests, but with one test I noticed that finding the intersect of two spans of vectors could give wrong results due to limited numerical accuracy, so I added rounding (using tol=13 seems to omit errors in my case).

Once you have your Kalman decomposition then the minimal realisation of the state space model can be constructed using:

```
list = N(1) + 1:N(1) + N(2);
Am = Ak(list,list);
Bm = Bk(list,:);
Cm = Ck(:,list);
Dm = D;
```

If you just want to minimal realisation then you might be able to calculate it faster. But you do need to ensure that the total $M$ matrix is square and full rank.

Comment: So with this...I can find which states who are not controllable and observable and remove them ?

Comment: Or can I not take SVD of controllbility gramian to check what state is controllable or not ?

Comment: Can I use eigensystem realization algorithm(ERA) or Ho Kalman IR algorithm ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I never really liked Gramians so I prefer the controllability and observability matrices. However the PBH-test does not use either, it just enabled you to find which mode with a certain eigenvalue is not controllable or observable. The corresponding eigenvectors can therefore be used as well to identify the similarity transformation that brings the system into the Kalman decomposition. I am not familiar with eigensystem realization algorithm or Ho Kalman IR algorithm.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I initially did not recognize ERA by its name, but I do recognize the formulation. It is usually used for system identification. However you could simulate the non-minimal state space model, with zero initial state and impulse as input, and then identify, but it will probably be more computationally intensive then other methods. And due to numerical errors it might still be able that uncontrollable modes might get identified, especially if their dynamics are unstable.

Comment: So if all those methods named in this question have uncertainties. Which one is the best then ? Should I just skip the minimal realization and focus more on model reduction and balanced realization and balanced model reduction?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Your initial question is about finding the minimal state space realisation. What your are asking now would be another question by itself. But MATLAB states the following on its page about the minreal function: "Pole-zero cancellation is a straightforward search through the poles and zeros looking for matches that are within tolerance. Transfer functions are first converted to zero-pole-gain form.". Earlier on it also mentions a Kalman decomposition, so I am not sure what MATLAB actually uses. And I also have had problems with minreal not giving the result I expected.

Comment: You had problems with MATLAB library itself when you do a minimal state space realization?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: You should upvote and accept the answer to your question and then ask a new question about the other details that you are interested in.

Comment: @MrYouMath I still asking if this method (minimal realization) is good or give half good state space models. If it's OK. Then I accept.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: You didn't ask this in your first post, hence it is not part of the initial question.

Comment: @MrYouMath I think this is a good answer for the question, so I accept it now and vote up.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson You are asking good questions :). I am looking forward to your next question ;-).

Comment: Where can I read more about this minimal realization method ?

Comment: It seems that Ho & Kalman system identification algorithm will create a minimal realization of a state space model.